# Автоматическое обновление цены

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Имеется форма, на которой инпут с выбором срока.  
Необходимо, чтобы после изменения значения в инпуте автоматически генерировалась и выводилась без перезагрузки страницы цена, которая находится ниже в блоке div (Алгоритм вычисления цены - Значение инпута * 20).

Нашел вот это:

```
onchange="document.getElementById('total').innerHTML='текст'"
```

Но не знаю, как реализовать при помощи этого то, что я написал выше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так можно реализовать с помощью предложенной вами строки:

```
<input type="text" onchange="document.getElementById('total').innerHTML=parseFloat(20*this.value)" />
<div id="total"></div>
```

А [здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/4tscpbLn/) можно посмотреть, как работает.

**Обновление**

http://jsfiddle.net/4tscpbLn/1/ вот так можно оптимизировать, чтобы считалось сразу. По поводу индикатора загрузки, это уже совсем другая история, создайте отдельную тему и сформулируйте логику этого индикатора, и вам помогут найти оптимальное решение.

**Обновление 2**

[[@Ilya78rus](/users/24113/ilya78rus)](/users/24113/ilya78rus), это обычный html-код, в который можно делать любые вставки, возможные для html, к примеру, на php это будет так:

```
echo '<input type="text" onchange="document.getElementById('total').innerHTML=parseFloat('.php-вставка.'*this.value)" />';
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но можно как то оптимизировать код, чтобы сумма автоматически вычислялась сразу после нажатия цифры на клавиатуре?  
И как к этому коду можно добавить индикатор загрузки?)

Comment: Спасибо большое.  
А если значение, на которое надо умножать, берется из mysql или из массива?

Comment: Спасибо, со всем разобрался